# How do I specify a specific database in a SQL server when creating an ODBC connection on Windows?

Tags: sql-server, r, database, odbc

I am working off of a server housing various `SQL` databases (accessed via `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio`) and am going to use `R` to perform analyses and explore a specific database within the server.  I have network security that permits communication between machines, drivers installed on the `R` server, and `RODBC` installed.

When I attempt to establish a Windows `ODBC` connection in the `Control panel>Administrative>Data Sources`,  I can only add a data source for the entirety of the `SQL` server, not just for the specifc database I want to look at. I pasted the code I have been experimenting with below.

```
library(RODBC)
channel <- odbcConnect("Example", uid="xxx", pwd=****");
sqlTables(channel) 
sqlTables(ch, tableType = "TABLE") 
res <- sqlFetch(ch, "samp.le", max = 15) #not recognizing as a table

library(RODBC)
ch <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={"SQL Server"}; server=Example; database=dbasesample; uid="xxxx", pwd = "****"')
```

### Response: Warning messages:

```
1: In odbcDriverConnect("driver={\"SQL Server\"}; server=sample; database=dbasesample; uid=\"xxxx", pwd = \"xxxx\"") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
2: In odbcDriverConnect("driver={\"SQL Server\"}; server=sample; database=dbasesample; uid=\"xxxx\", pwd = \"xxxx!\"") :
  ODBC connection failed
```

Any insight into this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: While the Data Source name may not let you build a connection to a specific database, it should let you define a default database. Did you receive a success message when you tested the DSN when you set it up using the wizard?

Comment: Yes, I rececieved a success message when I tested the DSN. So are you suggesting I set the default database to the one I want to work on? Thank you for your insight.

Comment: I have typically created separate DSNs for each database, just for the convenience of not having to type `[database].[schema].[table].[field]`.  But I would expect if the test passes when you define the DSN, that you should be able to connect from R.  Have you run `RODBC::odbcDataSources()` to see if R is seeing your DSN?

Comment: Thank you Benjamin! I went back through setting up a DSN and defined the default database to the one I wanted to access on the server, the default setting was a master database detailing the contents of the server.  Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Although while querying with the sqlQuery() function you can specify database, schema and table, e.g.

```
library(RODBC)
con = odbcConnect(dsn = 'local')    
sample_query = sqlQuery(con,'select * from db.dbo.table')
```

I have not found a way to define the database from within the function parameters while using sqlFetch() or sqlSave(). An indirect way would be to define the default database in the dsn (as written in the comments). But then, you would need a different dsn for each database you would like to use.
A better solution would be to use the odbc and DBI packages instead of RODBC, and define the database in the connection statement e.g.

```
library(dplyr)
library(DBI)
library(odbc)

con <- dbConnect(dsn = 'local',database = 'db')
copy_to(con, rr2, temporary = F)
```

By the way, I found copy_to to be much faster than the equivalent sqlSave of RODBC.